# Multipath configuration is ignoring drives after /dev/sdaa, /dev/sdab, etc

Tags: iscsi, multipath

I have a bare metal server running on Softlayer. It has many Consistent Performance iSCSI storage devices attached in a [multipath configuration](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/accessing-block-storage-consistent-performance-linux).

One of the devices, represented by /dev/sdaa1 and /dev/sdab1, is not showing up as a multipath device under /dev/mapper.

How can I make it show up?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the multipath blacklist in `/etc/multipath.conf` had been amended to exclude /dev/sda1:

```
devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st|sda|sdb|sdc)[0-9]*"
```

The regex above catches /dev/sda1 as intended, but it also catches /dev/sdaa1 and /dev/sda_foobar. To fix, amend the blacklist to include the end of the device name:

```
devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st|sda|sdb|sdc)[0-9]*$"
```

After amending the blacklist, reload the configuration:

```
service multipathd reload
```